# Find longitude and latitude of a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, google-maps

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df

id  Description
1   POS Transfer A&W MONTREAL QC
2   MKLI QC Montreal DOLLARAMA
3   PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```

I am trying to get the address from the description. What I did:

```
provinces=["qc","on"]

b=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c=0
    for i in provinces:
        if i in row["Description"].lower().split():
            a=[row["id"],row["description"]]
            c=1
            break
    if(c==1):        
        b.append(a)


b 

[[0, 'POS Transfer A&W MONTREAL QC'],
 [1, ' MKLI QC Montreal DOLLARAMA ']]
```

Here I am capturing the information in an array. Can I directly capture it in an additional pandas column

Here, I captured all the description where there is an address. In order to send this to google api, I just want to select the 1 word on left and right of the province. That is in the case of :

```
POS Transfer A&W MONTREAL QC
```

I want to capture:

```
A&W MONTREAL QC
```

In the case of

```
MKLI QC Montreal DOLLARAMA
```

I want to capture

```
QC Montreal DOLLARAMA
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are `provinces=["qc","on"]` ? then `I just want to select the 1 word on left and right of the province.` is not expected output. there is typo?

Comment: I am checking for only two provinces. What I am doing is if in the description column, there is a “qc” or “on”, I create a new column with the words to the left and right of the word

Comment: So need 2 word before province and 2 word after?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need for select 1 word before and after `province`:

```
provinces=["qc","on"]

def f(x):
    #convert to lowercast splitted list for find
    x1 = x.lower().split()
    x2 = x.split()
    #get indices of search word with one word before and after
    #min and max is for avoid indexing errors 
    out = [' '.join(x2[max(0, i-1): min(len(x), i+2)]) for i, y in enumerate(x1) 
                                                       if y in provinces]
    #return first matched value if exist
    return out[0] if len(out) > 0 else ''


df['new'] = df['Description'].apply(f)
print (df)
   id                     Description               new
0   1    POS Transfer A&W MONTREAL QC       MONTREAL QC
1   2      MKLI QC Montreal DOLLARAMA  MKLI QC Montreal
2   3  PC - PAYMENT FROM - *****11*22
```